# dplyr's mutate at each column separately with a custom function of several parametrs

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following function which I would like to apply to a data frame's columns:

```
ff <- function(w, epsi, df) {
  res <- w*(max(df, na.rm = T) - min(df, na.rm=T)+2*epsi)+min(df, na.rm = T) - epsi
  return(res)
}
```

the function should be applied to each column of `w`, using the parameters `epsi` and `df`. The function has to take each value of `w` and multiply it by the max of the corresponding column of `df` minus the min of that column of `df`, and so on.

For example:

```
> w
# A tibble: 5 x 2
    A       B
  <dbl>   <dbl>
1 0.290  0.928  
2 0.917  0.929  
3 0.910  0.919  
4 0.243  0.908  
5 0.936  0.901
```

and `df` is:

```
> df
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   A     B
  <dbl> <dbl>
1 0.977 1.03 
2 1.04  1.15 
3 0.929 0.875
4 1.12  1.15 
5 0.913 1.05 
6 1.00  1.09 
7 0.972 1.03 
8 0.919 1.04 
9 0.935 0.973
10 1.08  1.17
```

So for the first element of `w`, 0.290, the function multiplies 0.290 by the max of `df` in column `A` (1.12), and so on.

How can I apply the function using `dplyr` to `w`?

I tried:

```
w_new = w %>%  mutate_each(ff(w,0.001, df))
```

But instead of accepting only one column at a time, it tries to operate on all the columns at once.

Comment: Can you add the expected output based on your sample `df` and `w`?

Comment: For the first element of w the function outputs: `0.290*(1.12-0.913+0.002)+0.913-0.001 = 0.97261`, and so on for each element of column A, and then the same for column B, so the output is a 5x2 data frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP has expressed desire to use `dplyr` based solution for this problem hence I thought to provide an answer using `dplyr`.

In the situations where we need to look for a corresponding column (name) in another table then its always better not to rely on order of columns ranter use specific column names. The `quo_name` and `quo` functions provides access to column name in scope of `dplyr::mutate_all` function.

A solution using `dplyr::mutate_all` can be as:

```
# Re-wirte fucntion to accept the column name for df
ff <- function(x, epsi, colName) {
  res <- x*(max(df[,colName], na.rm = TRUE) - min(df[,colName], na.rm=TRUE) +
         2*epsi)+min(df[,colName], na.rm = TRUE) - epsi
  return(res)
}

library(dplyr)

# The corresponding column names is passed to ff using quo_name(quo(.))
w %>% mutate_all(funs(ff(., 0.001, quo_name(quo(.)) )))
#          A        B
# 1 0.972610 1.149616
# 2 1.103653 1.149913
# 3 1.102190 1.146943
# 4 0.962787 1.143676
# 5 1.107624 1.141597
```

**Data:**

```
w <- read.table(text = 
"A       B
1 0.290  0.928  
2 0.917  0.929  
3 0.910  0.919  
4 0.243  0.908  
5 0.936  0.901",
header = TRUE)


df <- read.table(text = 
"A     B
1 0.977 1.03 
2 1.04  1.15 
3 0.929 0.875
4 1.12  1.15 
5 0.913 1.05 
6 1.00  1.09 
7 0.972 1.03 
8 0.919 1.04 
9 0.935 0.973
10 1.08  1.17",
header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is base R solution using `mapply`

```
mapply(
    function(x, y, epsi = 0.001)
        x * (max(y, na.rm = T) - min(y, na.rm = T) + 2 * epsi) + min(y, na.rm = T) - epsi,
    w, df)
#            A        B
#[1,] 0.972610 1.149616
#[2,] 1.103653 1.149913
#[3,] 1.102190 1.146943
#[4,] 0.962787 1.143676
#[5,] 1.107624 1.141597
```

Explanation: `mapply` applies the function to `w` and `df` column by column, and simplifies the result to a 5x2 `matrix`.

Redefining `ff` slightly, this can be written more succinctly as

```
ff <- function(x, y, epsi = 0.001)
    x * (max(y, na.rm = T) - min(y, na.rm = T) + 2 * epsi) + min(y, na.rm = T) - epsi
mapply(ff, w, df)
```

or using `purrr::map2_df` as

```
w %>% map2_df(df, ff)
## A tibble: 5 x 2
#      A     B
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1 0.973  1.15
#2 1.10   1.15
#3 1.10   1.15
#4 0.963  1.14
#5 1.11   1.14
```

---

### Update

Results from a very quick&dirty `microbenchmark` analysis of the `mutate_all` and `map2` approaches look like this:

```
res <- microbenchmark(
    map2 = {
        ff <- function(x, y, epsi = 0.001)
            x * (max(y, na.rm = T) - min(y, na.rm = T) + 2 * epsi) + min(y, na.rm = T) - epsi
        w %>% map2_df(df, ff)
    },
    mutate_all = {
        ff <- function(x, epsi, colName) {
            res <- x*(max(df[,colName], na.rm = TRUE) - min(df[,colName], na.rm=TRUE) +
         2*epsi)+min(df[,colName], na.rm = TRUE) - epsi
            return(res)
        }
        w %>% mutate_all(funs(ff(., 0.001, quo_name(quo(.)) )))
    }
)
res
#Unit: microseconds
#       expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#       map2  320.537  371.1365  495.7786  397.6755  449.4445  8599.661   100
# mutate_all 1916.788 1998.2105 2312.5878 2059.7650 2290.1415 11169.320   100

library(ggplot2)
autoplot(res)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That's how I eventually did this too. However it would be interesting to know if there is a `mutate` solution as well.

Comment: @OmryAtia I don't think this is possible with `mutate`, because you need to loop through both `w` and `df` column by column. You *could* define a function that matches column names between `w` and `df` and then conditional on matching column names converts values from `w`. That would be quite a cumbersome approach. I'd say this is good example case for the use of `mapply`/`Map` or `purrr::map2`.

Comment: @OmryAtia Well, I stand corrected;-) Not sure if the `mutate_all` plus quosure syntax solution is more elegant though, I'd still go for `map2` but that's obviously personal preference.

Comment: Well, for me speed is the main issue, and it doesn't look like one is preferable to the other in that respect. Still, nice to know the option exists!

Comment: @OmryAtia I've added a quick&dirty `microbenchmark` analysis (it's quick & dirty because you probably want to test this on larger datasets). The `map2` approach is noticeably faster, I imagine that this is a robust effect also for larger datasets.